# Реконструкция

Tags: php

Как закрывать свой сайт на реконструкцию?
Какой нужен код? Я знаю, что здесь надо приводить пример кодом!

Comment: А index заменить религия не позволяет?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А я знаю, что

> Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Но не суть. Как вариант можно: 
- mod_rewrite переписывать все запросы к сайту на reconstruct.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.yoursite.com/reconstruct.html [L]
```

- делать редирект всех запросов на эту же страничку.
  А на страничке находится сообщение, что сайт на реконструкции.

Comment: добавлю, в файле reconstruct.html можно написать

    exit("Сайт на реконструкции");